# How to serialize a simple list of string with Django and Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have setup my Django and Django Rest Framework and I'm trying to setup my model to have a list of strings.

Here's my code

**model.py**

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class TagModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class EventModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(TagModel)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "events"
        ordering = ['-createdAt']

        def __str__(self) -> str:
            return self.title
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import EventModel, TagModel


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TagModel
        fields = '__all__'


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EventModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

My code works but not what I expected. I tried on postman to do a `GET` and `POST` request.

The `GET` request seems to work well, but the `POST` request works but only with a dictionary like the following

```
{
            "title": "My example title",
            "tags": [{"name":"string"}, {"name":"pokemon"}]
}
```

but I wanna send something simpler like this

```
{
            "title": "My example title",
            "tags": ["string", "pokemon"]
}
```

how to make this happen?

**Note: I don't use POSTGRESQL**

**UPDATE 1 and I've found a solution**

I checked it out on chatGPT and it says to edit serializer.py to this way, but is it the normal way to do it?

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import EventModel

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EventModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        tags_string = ','.join(tags_data)  # Joining list into a comma-separated string
        event = EventModel.objects.create(tags=tags_string, **validated_data)
        return event

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags', None)
        if tags_data is not None:
            instance.tags = ','.join(tags_data)
            instance.save()
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['tags'] = instance.tags.split(',') if instance.tags else []
        return representation
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **SlugRelatedField** . It takes params `queryset`, `many` and `slug_field`.

```py
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=TagModel.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        slug_field='name'
     )

    class Meta:
        model = EventModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield